# understanding filter_input and its properties

Tags: php, validation, email, filter-input

Given the following code below :

```
if (isset($_POST['validate']) && trim($_POST['email']) != '') {
    //validate POST input
    $validatePOST = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    echo '<div style="background-color:yellow;padding:10px;color:#000;font-size:16px;">POST METHOD</div>';
    if ($validatePOST) {
        echo '<div style="background-color:green;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">
            <b>' . $_POST['email'] . '</b> is a valid email address
          </div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;color:#fff;font-size:16px;">
            <b>' . $_POST['email'] . '</b> is  not a valid email address
          </div>';
    }
}
```

Now, if I was teaching PHP in an english class, is my interpretation as follows right?

```
$validatePOST = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
```

When you say `filter_input(INPUT_POST , 'email')` basically what I am saying is:

> Hey `filter_input` can you go check `$_POST['email']`

And when I add the following filter (in this case `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL`):

I.e. `filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

I am basically saying:

> Hey `filter_input` can you go check `$_POST['email']` if it's actually an email or something else?

Comment: It validates whether `$_POST['email']` exists and looks like an email address.

Comment: @Ja͢ck is my interpretation correct ??